# Button flash animation android java

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

So I want to create a button which always flash if my boolean is set to true or with a timer. My first idea was to use the "on click" animation but I don't know if it would work fine. If you got an idea of how to make a flash animation please tell me.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: i dont know how to activate rhe on click anim or to create a flash of a normal button with a timer

Comment: You made the tutorial? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: thx yes i think it could work